# How to abort LocalServerSocket.accept

Tags: android, sockets, abort

How to abort/interrupt a LocalServerSocket waiting, in a background thread, for a connection in method LocalServerSocker.accept() ?

I've tried to call close() method from another thread, but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

There is a ticket opened for it in Android project: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29939.

Seems the problem is confirmed by Google, as the first comment is:

> i think we should rewrite this to use the same underlying libcore
>   stuff, and get the interruption behavior for free.

The workaround can be to send a custom shutdown command to the LocalServerSocket from another thread to unblock accept.

Comment: do you mean I need to write a subclass of LocalServerSocket and add an parameter to kill the thread?

Comment: No, in my case it was the separate thread that connect to local socket that unblocks accept(), so the LocalServerSocket thread can close socket and exit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `localSocket.close`, use this: (requires API 21+)

```
try {
    Os.shutdown(localSocket.fileDescriptor, OsConstants.SHUT_RDWR)
} catch (e: ErrnoException) {
    if (e.errno != OsConstants.EBADF) throw e   // suppress fd already closed
}
```